# Prove that $A=B$ according to the conditions involving relative complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if the relative complement of $A$ with respect to a set $E$ is equal to the relative complement of $B$ with respect to a set $E$, then $A=B$.

Comment: And you need to note that $A\cup B\subset E$. For example it is not true if $E$ is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You want to prove that if $A^c = B^c$, then $A = B$. Take $x \in A$. Then $x \not\in A^c = B^c$. Which means...

Comment: x∈B => A⊂B, same thing for B => B⊂A => A=B. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. $x \in A \implies x \in B$ means that $A \subset B$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

In general $A=(A^c)^c$ is true.